# Image button not wrapping content android

Tags: android, layout

in the below image, i have 3 imageButtions aligned in a horizontal scroll view. each of these buttons is sourcing an image, and *should* be taking up the complete size of the image. However, the Facebook button isn't. Ive triple checked - all three buttons are exactly the same size, and all three are set to wrap_content (see code below)

can anybody see what is going on and how to fix it?

[image: Scrollview]

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView2"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp">



            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/facebook"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/facebookbutton"
                android:background="@null"
                android:padding="5dp"/>


            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/facebook"
                android:id="@+id/twitter"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/twitterbutton"
                android:background="@null"
                android:padding="5dp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/twitter"
                android:id="@+id/contact"

                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/contactbutton"
                android:background="@null"
                android:padding="5dp"/>



        </RelativeLayout>


    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: did you manage to fix this? I am having a similar problem

Comment: actually u should've tried this attribute of the ImageButton: android:scaleType